# OnComponentLocalizePre method is not getting fired - Event System

Tags: event-system

I am new to the Tridion and trying to use the event system in Tridion but at one point i have been stucked while using the OnComponentLocalizePre method. I have used below given arguments.
OnComponentLocalizePre Component LocalizeEventArgs Initiated

I have used the below code line to subscribe the event.

EventSystem.Subscribe(OnComponentLocalizePre, EventPhases.Initiated);

I am just trying to append some text in the description on OnComponentLocalizePre event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which tridion system version you are using

Comment: It seems you are mixing the R5.x/2009 event system with the 2011/2013 event system

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your event handler isn't triggered?

I think the actual issue is that it's just not possible to change the Component in the initiated phase of a Localize event. Note that the initiated phase occurs just **before** the Localize action, so when the Component is still shared.

If you want to change a Local Copy's properties, you should subscribe to the processed phase and do an explicit Save to get your changes persisted.